# Counting number of element in array of list

Tags: c#, arrays, list, loops

Please, I have array of list and i want to find the count of all element.
example if i had array of 5 list and two list have 10 element and the rest having 15, so the count will be = ((2*10)+(3*15))= 65, if there any professional way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<int>[] arrList = new List<int>[3];
arrList[0] = new List<int>{1,2,3};
arrList[1] = new List<int>{1,2,3};
arrList[2] = new List<int>{1,2};

int cnt = arrList.Sum(l => l.Count); // 8
```